# Remove all non-"word characters" from a String in Java, leaving accented characters?

Tags: java, regex, string

Apparently Java's Regex flavor counts Umlauts and other special characters as non-"word characters" when I use Regex.

```
        "TESTÜTEST".replaceAll( "\\W", "" )
```

returns "TESTTEST" for me. What I want is for only all truly non-"word characters" to be removed. Any way to do this without having something along the lines of

```
         "[^A-Za-z0-9äöüÄÖÜßéèáàúùóò]"
```

only to realize I forgot ô?

Comment: The whole Unicode reference [http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html)

Answer (score 163, accepted):

Use `[^\p{L}\p{Nd}]+` - this matches all (Unicode) characters that are neither letters nor (decimal) digits.

In Java:

```
String resultString = subjectString.replaceAll("[^\\p{L}\\p{Nd}]+", "");
```

**Edit:**

I changed `\p{N}` to `\p{Nd}` because the former also matches some number symbols like `¼`; the latter doesn't. See it on [regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/lP8pG9).

Comment: Why the `\\[` inside your character class?

Comment: works like a charm! but does not replace 'º', 'ª', '¼'. since i only have this one 'º' I used .replaceAll("[^\\p{L}\\p{N}]|º", ""); any suggestion on how can I remove does others?

Answer (score 7):

I was trying to achieve the exact opposite when I bumped on this thread.
I know it's quite old, but here's my solution nonetheless.
You can use blocks, see [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#ubc).
In this case, compile the following code (with the right imports):

```
> String s = "äêìóblah"; 
> Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\\p{InLatin-1Supplement}]+"); // this regex uses a block
> Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
> System.out.println(m.find());
> System.out.println(s.replaceAll(p.pattern(), "#"));
```

You should see the following output:

> true
>
> #blah

Best,

Answer (score 6):

At times you do not want to simply remove the characters, but just remove the accents. I came up with the following utility class which I use in my Java REST web projects whenever I need to include a String in an URL:

```
import java.text.Normalizer;
import java.text.Normalizer.Form;

import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

/**
 * Utility class for String manipulation.
 * 
 * @author Stefan Haberl
 */
public abstract class TextUtils {
    private static String[] searchList = { "Ä", "ä", "Ö", "ö", "Ü", "ü", "ß" };
    private static String[] replaceList = { "Ae", "ae", "Oe", "oe", "Ue", "ue",
            "sz" };

    /**
     * Normalizes a String by removing all accents to original 127 US-ASCII
     * characters. This method handles German umlauts and "sharp-s" correctly
     * 
     * @param s
     *            The String to normalize
     * @return The normalized String
     */
    public static String normalize(String s) {
        if (s == null)
            return null;

        String n = null;

        n = StringUtils.replaceEachRepeatedly(s, searchList, replaceList);
        n = Normalizer.normalize(n, Form.NFD).replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "");

        return n;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a clean representation of a String which might be used safely
     * within an URL. Slugs are a more human friendly form of URL encoding a
     * String.
     * <p>
     * The method first normalizes a String, then converts it to lowercase and
     * removes ASCII characters, which might be problematic in URLs:
     * <ul>
     * <li>all whitespaces
     * <li>dots ('.')
     * <li>(semi-)colons (';' and ':')
     * <li>equals ('=')
     * <li>ampersands ('&')
     * <li>slashes ('/')
     * <li>angle brackets ('<' and '>')
     * </ul>
     * 
     * @param s
     *            The String to slugify
     * @return The slugified String
     * @see #normalize(String)
     */
    public static String slugify(String s) {

        if (s == null)
            return null;

        String n = normalize(s);
        n = StringUtils.lowerCase(n);
        n = n.replaceAll("[\\s.:;&=<>/]", "");

        return n;
    }
}
```

Being a German speaker I've included proper handling of German umlauts as well - the list should be easy to extend for other languages.

HTH

**EDIT:** Note that it *may* be unsafe to include the returned String in an URL. You should at least HTML encode it to prevent XSS attacks.

Comment: important info on this, u can get the StringUtils class / package etc. @ http://commons.apache.org/lang/download_lang.cgi

Comment: You never used slugify

Comment: @Star `slugify` is a public utility method to use in the rest of your code.

Answer (score 2):

Well, here is one solution I ended up with, but I hope there's a more elegant one...

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
for(int i=0; i<name.length(); i++) {
    char tmpChar = name.charAt( i );
    if (Character.isLetterOrDigit( tmpChar) || tmpChar == '_' ) {
        result.append( tmpChar );
    }
}
```

`result` ends up with the desired result...

Comment: The fact that your variable String is named `name` suggests it won't be a large String. But in cases that it does get large (a couple of thousands of characters), I'd go with the for-statement as you did now.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to [remove the accents and diacritic signs first](http://www.drillio.com/en/software-development/java/removing-accents-diacritics-in-any-language/), then on each character position check if the "simplified" string is an ascii letter - if it is, the original position shall contain word characters, if not, it can be removed.

Comment: Class java.text.Normalizer is not supported before android API level 9, so if your app must be compatible with API level 8 (13% of total devices, according to Google's Android dashboard), this method is not viable