# How can we remove (or detect) non english tags from a tweet without external resources with JAVA

Tags: java, tags

How can I remove non english tags from a tweet with keeping hashtags (#xxx), urls (@xxxx) and mentions (@xxx)?
I found this :
content.replaceAll("\W", " ")
here : [Remove all non-"word characters" from a String in Java, leaving accented characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1611979/1515897), but it doesn't really help.
I know there are many language detection tools like the microsoft one's, and other complicated methods, but i want some regular expressions, or methods that I can use in JAVA, without an external resource (like dictionaries).
This is an example of tweet : "Meeeeeee ! RT @missLOVElace_: who wants my 80,000 tweet ?"

If there are methods in JAVA that can detect if the tweet is in non english language it will be very great. A similar one is here : 
http://babel-fett.heroku.com/
but it is in Ruby.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you read the link labeled 'more information'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the java regex : content.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9-_@#\s]", "")... it works.. 
I'm searching for a java language detector; I'm looking for a robust tool that works offline.. I found this one : http://code.google.com/p/language-detection/wiki/GettingStarted
And I think it's a good one.
Other related questions are here : https://stackoverflow.com/q/1923844/1515897, [How to detect language of user entered text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3227524/how-to-detect-language-of-user-entered-text).

Answer (score 0):

Well there are 2 conditions for a word not to be English (and it a word isn't English, you can conclude the phrase isn't, normally).

1 - Check if the first letter isn't capital : a proper noun remains inchanged, whatever the language is

2 - All English letters are contained in [a-zA-Z], so I guess it's not really difficult to check whether or not a word is English. Here is a **non exhaustive** list of character which, for instance, doesn't exist in English :

```
äàáãæå
ëèéê
ïìíî
òóôö
ð
ñ
```

But basically, every word which doesn't match `\w` isn't English... (Except if the first letter of the word is a capital one, I repeat).

But see, even the tool which is online does like this. Take the sentence **Hoark blerk**, which has no sense, your tool detects it as English, because I didn't use any non-\w letters. So if you really want to go deep, you'll have to create a database with all English words (I think it already exist) and check whether your words match any entry of the dictionnary... But I doubt you really wanna be so precise.

Remember to keep the `@whatever` and `#whatever_again`, with and without parenthesis (which can be very easily achived using a simple regex). And don't forget to ignore ponctuation, like smileys etc. Except if a language includes those symbols as letters, you should just keep them ;)

Comment: But this may still leave you with enough foreign phrases. "Das ist toll." totally matches it and still isnt English at all.

Comment: That's true, hence my remark about the dictionnary. Removing all non \w words makes half of the work, then I think only working with a dictionnary will help... Otherwise he can use probabilities, just like the creator of the Ruby API did : http://blog.echen.me/2011/05/01/unsupervised-language-detection-algorithms/

Comment: True. Your edit came while I was typing my comment. In essence, i guess it's not as easy as the poster wishes it to be.

Comment: Thank you very much, and what about the java code I should use to filter out non english words and keep those like @whatever and #whatever_again, I did many research about regular expressions in this sense, but i didn't found a real answer. I'm searching the code :)
for the dictionary, i can't use it at this moment...
we should keep in mind that we are dealing with tweets, so we can encounter tags like : looooool, coool, smileys, and many others sentenses like that.. saying that : "if a word isn't English, you can conclude the phrase isn't, normally" have no sense, isn't?

Comment: Well, i will do other researches on regular expressions in JAVA, and if i find any useful information, i will put it here.