# Identify valid characters of a character array

Tags: java, arrays

I am receiving a character array where it has valid and invalid characters. I need to only retrieve the characters that are valid. How can I do this ?

```
char[]ch = str.toCharacterArray();
for(int i=0;i<ch.length.i++){
    if(!Character.isLetter(ch[i]))
         system.out.println("not valid");
    else  
        system.out.println("valid");
}
```

I don't think the above code works because I get invalid for all the valid and invalid characters in the character array.

by meaning characters I am expecting all alphanumeric and special characters

**Note**: I am getting values from the server, therefore the character array contains valid and invalid characters.

Comment: You start off by talking about a *byte array* but then you talk about *characters*, and your code has a *string*. Which is it? And what sort of "invalid characters" do you mean?

Comment: I don't see a good reason why the server should be giving you invalid characters unless you are getting binary data which happens to contain some text and you don't know what to do with the rest of the content.  There are is only two characters defined as invalid but I suspect you want printable characters.

Comment: I have edited the post, Yes i want to have printable characters.

Comment: If the server is not broken, then it's sending you "correct" data in some format. I can't imagine a case where plucking the printable characters out of the data is preferably to truly understanding the format and extracting what you know must be the data you care about.

Comment: So you just want letter/numbers, and remove all spaces and other symbols or control chars?

Comment: Look at  Tim Pietzcker answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611979/remove-all-non-word-characters-from-a-string-in-java-leaving-accented-charact)

Comment: Your code is checking just letters (no numbers or special characters), but beside that you should check if you maybe have any encoding problems first. In that case event regexp will not help you. Are you sure that string created from bytes that server sends is well generated?

Answer (score 1):

try following method:

```
// assume input is not too large string
public static String extractPrintableChars(final String input) {
    String out = input;
    if(input != null) {
        char[] charArr = input.toCharArray();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();  
        for (char ch : charArr) {
            if(Character.isDefined(ch) && !Character.isISOControl(ch)) {
                sb.append(ch);
            }
        }
        out = sb.toString();
    }
    return out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into Matcher class available in java. I don't think it to be wise to loop over all the characters until there is a max Cap for it.

```
/[^0-9]+/g, ''
```

with above regEx it will wipe out all the charecters other then numeric with noting. Modify it as per your need.

regards
Punith