# Extract the noun words & original sentence from POS Tag

Tags: java, regex, nlp, opennlp

I want to extract the nouns from the sentence and get back the original sentence from the POS Tag

```
 //Extract the words before _NNP & _NN from below  and also how to get back the original sentence from the Pos TAG. 
 Original Sentence:Hi. How are you? This is Mike·
 POSTag: Hi._NNP How_WRB are_VBP you?_JJ This_DT is_VBZ Mike._NN
```

I tried something like this

```
    String txt = "Hi._NNP How_WRB are_VBP you?_JJ This_DT is_VBZ Mike._NN";


    String re1 = "((?:[a-z][a-z0-9_]*))";   // Variable Name 1
    String re2 = ".*?"; // Non-greedy match on filler
    String re3 = "(_)"; // Any Single Character 1
    String re4 = "(NNP)";   // Word 1

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(re1 + re2 + re3 + re4, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(txt);
    if (m.find()) {
        String var1 = m.group(1);
        System.out.print(  var1.toString()  );
    }
}
```

output: Hi 
But I need a list of all the nouns in the sentence.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? `[a-zA-Z](?=[.]_NN)` will capture any alphachar-string followed by `._NN`, maybe you could start with it.

Comment: You have a typo in your example.  In the first block, "Mike." is followed by "_NN", but in the second block it is followed by "_NNP".

Comment: that is a type of noun which is proper noun I get the pos tag something which gives me different types of nouns

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**To extract the nouns**, you can do this:

```
public static String[] extractNouns(String sentenceWithTags) {
    // Split String into array of Strings whenever there is a tag that starts with "._NN"
    // followed by zero, one or two more letters (like "_NNP", "_NNPS", or "_NNS")
    String[] nouns = sentenceWithTags.split("_NN\\w?\\w?\\b");
    // remove all but last word (which is the noun) in every String in the array
    for(int index = 0; index < nouns.length; index++) {
        nouns[index] = nouns[index].substring(nouns[index].lastIndexOf(" ") + 1)
        // Remove all non-word characters from extracted Nouns
        .replaceAll("[^\\p{L}\\p{Nd}]", "");
    }
    return nouns;
}
```

**To extract the original sentence**, you can do this:

```
public static String extractOriginal(String sentenceWithTags) {
    return sentenceWithTags.replaceAll("_([A-Z]*)\\b", "");
}
```

**Proof** that it works:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String sentence = "Hi._NNP How_WRB are_VBP you?_JJ This_DT is_VBZ Mike._NN";
    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(extractNouns(sentence)));
    System.out.println(extractOriginal(sentence));
}
```

**Output:**

```
[Hi, Mike]
Hi. How are you? This is Mike.
```

Note: for the regex that removed all non-word characters (like punctuation) from the extracted nouns, I used **[this Stack Overflow question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611979/remove-all-non-word-characters-from-a-string-in-java-leaving-accented-charact).**

Comment: Thank you for your reply James, it works perfectly for nouns NN but i need all of this NN - Noun, singular or mass, NNP-Proper Noun, singular, NNPS-Proper Noun, plural, NNS-Noun, plural and that is not the typo in the sentence.

Comment: I fixed the typo but how would I split different nouns because currently it only splits with noun ending _NN, I need to extract nouns with _NNP, _NNPS, _NNS as well.

Comment: @srp Oh, ok.  In that case, just add "\\w?\\w?" to the end of the regex "_NN\\b".  "\\w" finds a word character, and "?" means zero or one occurrences, so this will find "_NN" followed by zero, one, or two word characters.  Updating answer.

Comment: @srp EDIT:  modified regex in extractOriginal() method, much more robust now.

Comment: @James, you said in comments that     // remove all but last word (which is the noun) in every String in the array , this is adding the last word to the array of nouns all the time even though if that is not a noun and it is not compulsory that the last word is a noun every time. How would i eliminate this condition? Could you please tell me

Comment: @srp Maybe I'm not understanding how this tagging works... Shouldn't the last word before a noun tag always be a noun?  I did notice that "hi" is tagged as a noun even though it's not a noun.  Am I not understanding how these tags work?  How is it that sometimes the word right before the noun tag ("_NN", "_NNP", etc.) is not a noun?

Answer (score 1):

Use `while (m.find())` instead of `if (m.find())` to iterate over all the matches.

Moreover, your regex can be really simplified:

- if you don't need to capture the data, just don't put parenthesis (usually)
- you're using `((?:...))` which is quite strange: a non-capturing group directly nested within a capturing group has no sense.
- I'm not sure the `.*?` part does what you expect. If you want to match a dot, use `[.]` instead.

Thus, try `([a-z][a-z0-9_]*)[.]_NNP` instead.

Or even using positive lookahead: `[a-z][a-z0-9_]*(?=[.]_NNP)`. Use `m.group()` to access the captured data.

Answer (score 1):

This one should work

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Test {

public static final String NOUN_REGEX = "[a-zA-Z]*_NN\\w?\\w?\\b";

public static ArrayList<String> extractNounsByRegex(String sentenceWithTags) {
    ArrayList<String> nouns = new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] words = sentenceWithTags.split("\\s+");
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        if(words[i].matches(NOUN_REGEX)) {
            System.out.println(" Matched ");
            //remove the suffix _NN* and retain  [a-zA-Z]*
                nouns.add(words[i].replaceAll("_NN\\w?\\w?\\b", ""));
            }
        }
        return nouns;
    }

    public static String extractOriginal(String word) {
                return word.replaceAll("_NN\\w?\\w?\\b", "");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //        String sentence = "Hi._NNP How_WRB are_VBP you?_JJ This_DT is_VBZ Mike._NN";
        String sentence = "Eiffel_NNP tower_NN is_VBZ in_IN paris_NN Hi_NNP How_WRB are_VBP you_PRP This_DT is_VBZ Mike_NNP Barrack_NNP Obama_NNP is_VBZ a_DT president_NN this_VBZ";
        System.out.println(extractNounsByRegex(sentence).toString());
        System.out.println(sentence);
    }
}
```