# how to sort characters and remove punctuation in strings java

Tags: java, sorting, replace

Need some help, I need to remove white space and punctuation from user input word. Then sort it by rearranging the letters(no specific way).

my Problem is that i can either remove punctuation and spaces or I can sort the characters but i cant get it to do both. it just prints out the hex. Any help please.

public class Assignment6_main {

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a string: ");
    String s = input.nextLine();

    sort(s);

}

public static void sort(String myString) {

    char[] chars = myString.toCharArray();
```

//sort characters

```
    Arrays.sort(chars);
```

//remove punctuation and white space

```
    String noPuncs = myString.replaceAll("\\W", "");

    System.out.println(noPuncs + chars);
```

}
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You nearly had it. The \W looked like it needed to be escaped twice, and if you sort the String that had the characters removed, you could just print that:

```
public static void sort(String myString) {

   String noPuncs = myString.replaceAll("\\W", "");

   char[] chars = noPuncs.toCharArray();
   Arrays.sort(chars);
   System.out.println(chars);

} }
```

Comment: Thank you thank you all so much, spent two hours trying to figure this out. hope one day to by java jedi's like you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually convert the character array back to a string:

```
    System.out.println(noPuncs + new String(chars));
```

When you do a plain

```
    System.out.println(chars);
```

You are calling the println(char x[]), which is clever about making things look nice, but when you concatenate it with a String, you will call toString() on a primitive array, which is just going to give you an object reference.

Answer (score 0):

I'm think this what you want to do. You replace all the whitespace of the string FIRST, then you turn it into a char array and sort it. Also, "noPuncs" really isn't what this string is, it should be "noWhitespace". You haven't removed any punctuation as of yet.

```
public static void sort(String myString) {

    String noWhitespace = myString.replaceAll("\\W", "");
    char[] chars = noWhitespace.toCharArray();
    //sort characters

    Arrays.sort(chars);
    //remove punctuation and white space

    System.out.println(noWhitespace + new String(chars));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the punctuation, you might find some interesting informations from this [question in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611979/remove-all-non-word-characters-from-a-string-in-java-leaving-accented-charact)