# Adding exceptions to regular expressions (using android studio)

Tags: java, android, regex

I'm new to regular expressions I'm doing a java project and I'm trying to specify a string of characters that only include alphabetic characters plus, some special characters such as `ö`, `ä`,`å` and `ü`.

How can I specify all these in regex? So far I have this but it does not work:

```
return s.matches("^[a-zA-Z]*$ && [öäå]");
```

update:

ok so with this expression return `s.matches("^[\\p{L}\\p{Nd}]*$");` I get all characters including ö and Ä but not å and ü

Comment: try this: `return s.matches("^[a-zA-Zöäå]*$");`. And read the following answers in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611979/remove-all-non-word-characters-from-a-string-in-java-leaving-accented-charact I.e. that should work for you: `return s.matches("^[\p{L}\p{Nd}]*$");`

Comment: then what about those special characters in caps?

Comment: As described in the linked post "Use [^\p{L}\p{Nd}]+ - this matches all (Unicode) characters that are neither letters nor (decimal) digits." - just remove the negation for your scenario ... and maybe the numbers if you don't want them (remove this: \p{Nd})...

Comment: Try `return s.matches("(?i)^[a-zöäå]");`.

Comment: Did you have time to check `s.matches("(?i)^[a-zöäå]");`? Or as an alternative, `s.matches("(?ui)^[a-zöäå]");`?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the AND operator in regex expressions.

```
return s.matches("^[a-zA-Zöäåü]*$");
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: True, but not a general answer for all existing umlauts (e.g. the ü mentioned by OP is missing)

Comment: @Markus I think the intended question was not about how to include all existing umlauts in the regex. The user posted about how to include characters such as ö, ä, å and ü along with all the alphabets. So, I just indicated how that can be done. Still, I agree with not including ü in the expression.

Comment: ok so with this expression return s.matches("^[\\p{L}\\p{Nd}]*$"); I get all characters including ö and Ä but not å and  ü

Comment: Your requirements are not very clear to me. I would suggest you read [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html).

Comment: my requirements are all english alphabet letter PLUS ö, ä, ü (umlaut)

Comment: still not clear - also å and Ä, Ö, Ü - and what is with  È É ê è é ç?

Answer (score -1):

please try this:`"^([a-zA-Z]+|([öäå])+)[a-zA-Z]*$"`

Comment: Whats the difference to this: `"^[a-zA-Zöäå]*$"` except that it looks way more complicated for nothing?

Comment: it means the alphabetic characters or the special characters  must appear once,"^[a-zA-Zöäå]*$" can  match null value.

Comment: True ... but then why don't you just do this: `"^[a-zA-Zöäå]+$"`

Comment: Yes! you write more concise.

Answer (score -2):

could try something like this `^[a-zA-Zöäå]*$`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: he asked how he could specify it in a regex i gave him a regex how does that not provide an answer?