# How to detect non-words in a text?

Tags: java, string, nlp, opennlp

I would like to write an algorithm that let me to detect the non-words in a sentence. I'm working with french documents and I'm using an OCR to recognize sentences in it.

Sometimes, the OCR (Tess4J - Tesseract OCR for Java) recognize some parts of the document as words like signature or other non-words things.

In this way, I have got some weird result. See below an example:

```
l'intéressé(e) devra contacter le Ministère du_Développement durable et des Infrastructures pour se faire délivrer un permis de conduire. æ P CÂ_ä'”“":æ“"—g fin de document.
```

Here the sequence `æ P CÂ_ä'”“":æ“"—g` is not a word.

So, how can I detect these "weird" words and remove it?

Comment: Have you tried regex?

Comment: A quick google searched showed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611979/remove-all-non-word-characters-from-a-string-in-java-leaving-accented-charact)

Comment: I've been thinking about regexes, but "weird words" can have very different structure so I don't know how to write my regex.

Comment: Good DUP, just not sure if that fully addresses what the OP is asking for ...

Comment: I have tested the regex on the previous post but they don't solve my problem. They remove the non Unicode characters. My "weird words" still here